# SQL: smallest difference of time between a fixed event and multiple others

Tags: sql, datetime

I know the title might looks complicated, so I will try to do my best to explain it easily.
Imagine a production line where a product is the output of the building machine, and is used later in some machines (where the product is now the Input)

Let's imagine the life of MaterialX that is produced at DT1 and later consumed at DT3,DT3,DT4 in different machines:

```
Machine       IN           OUT             Datetime
--------------------------------------------------
PROD          ***        MaterialX            DT1
M1         MaterialX         ***              DT2
M2         MaterialX         ***              DT3
M3         MaterialX         ***              DT4
```

Same happens with different materials

```
Machine       IN           OUT             Datetime
--------------------------------------------------
PROD          ***        MaterialY            DT5
M1         MaterialY         ***              DT6
M2         MaterialY         ***              DT7
M5         MaterialY         ***              DT8
```

Note: Production is unique, while the product can be the input of 1 or many machines.

The output I would like to display is the time between production and first entry in a machine:

```
Material      Production     First Use
----------------------------------------
MaterialX        DT1            DT2
MaterialY        DT5            DT6
```

Any idea how it could be done?

**What I have tried:**

1) Create a view that displays all the productions (WHERE OUT like "Material%").

2) Create a view that displays all the machines use(WHERE IN like "Material%").

3) Join all these 2 views on prod.out=use.IN and try to get the smallest DateTime delta.

Still working on this idea, but I have some issues, and don't like to create 2 views just for that use case. Any better idea or a better approach is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two selections of the table, first the produced materials, next their usage. Join them on the material and output their creation time as well as the smallest time after creation:

```
SELECT PROD.Material, PROD.Datetime, MIN(USE.Datetime)
FROM
(
    SELECT OUT as MATERIAL, Datetime FROM your_table WHERE machine='PROD'
) AS PROD
JOIN
(
    SELECT IN as MATERIAL, Datetime FROM your_table WHERE machine<>'PROD'
) AS USE
ON USE.Material = PROD.Material
GROUP BY a.Material, a.Datetime
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
select x.out, x.datetime, min(p1.datetime)
from prod p1
inner join 
(
-- get the materials produced with their production time
select p2.out, p2.datetime 
from prod p2
where p2.out is not null
) x on p1.in = x.out
group by x.out, x.datetime
```